# Во время воспроизведения видео и выключается мп3 плеер в телефоне

Tags: android, mediaplayer, videoview

Подскажите, подключил VideoView в приложение. Все работает (видео изначально без звука), но...
Если у меня работает плеер в телефоне, и я захожу в Activity с VideoView и запускаю видео, плеер становится на паузу. Нужно сделать так, чтобы воспроизведение видео не мешало работе плеера.
Спасибо

```
 videoPlayer = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoplayer);
videoPlayer.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        videoPlayer.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        videoPlayer.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
        videoPlayer.start();
Uri myVideoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.prised);
            videoPlayer.setVideoURI(myVideoUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если кому то пригодится, нашел ответ!

```
videoView.setAudioFocusRequest(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_NONE);
```